# How to resize Image Input in order to have a new src property generated with the new width and height?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, type-conversion, image-resizing

I'm working on an Angular website, on a Image selector (in order to create thumbnail with set size). 
I use a file input for the user to upload his file, then I catch the event, do some verification (format and size), and I process to it's resizing. But this is currently not working at all.

I'm actually making some promise that converts the FileInput target to a base64 image, then I use it to create an Image() object in order to access the image's width and height.

I'm changing img.width and img.height properties and creating back a FileInput with my img.src in it.

I can't really do however I want as I'm using `ngx-image-cropper`, and I really need to push a resized image in the cropper.
`(ngx-image-cropper accepts FileEvent or Base64 img url)`

```js
// Proceed to the image resizing
  resizeImg(img) {
    if (img.width && img.height) {
      if (img.height > img.width && img.height > 280) {
        const coef = 280 / img.height;
        img.width = img.width * coef;
        img.height = img.height * coef;
      } else if (img.width > img.height && img.width > 280) {
        const coef = 280 / img.width;
        img.height = img.height * coef;
        img.width = img.width * coef;
      }
    }
    console.log(img.width);
    console.log(img.height);
    return img;
  }

  // Creates back the FileInput
  imageToFileInput(src, filename, imgType) {
    return fetch(src)
      .then(function(res) {
        return res.arrayBuffer();
      })
      .then(function(buf) {
        return new File([buf], filename, { type: imgType });
      });
  }

  // Promise that creates an Image() object with file's base64 url
  createImg(url) {
    return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
      const img = new Image();

      img.onload = function() {
        res(img);
      };
      img.src = url;
    });
  }

  // Promise that generate the image file's base64 url
  retrieveBase64Url(file) {
    return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function() {
        res(reader.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  }

  // Manages format/size errors then add file to cropper
  fileProcess(fileInput: any) {
    const file = fileInput.target.files[0];

    this.preview = false;
    if (
      file &&
      file.type !== 'image/png' &&
      file.type !== 'image/jpg' &&
      file.type !== 'image/jpeg'
    ) {
      // Format error gesture
      this.sizeError = false;
      this.formatError = true;
    } else if (file && file.size / 1000000 > this.maxSize) {
      // Size error gesture
      this.formatError = false;
      this.sizeError = true;
    } else {
      this.fileName = file.name;

      // Process to image resizing, apply it to file and then push it to the cropper
      this.retrieveBase64Url(file).then(url => {
        this.createImg(url).then(img => {
          const resized_img = this.resizeImg(img);
          this.imageToFileInput(resized_img.src, 'resized.png', 'image/png').then(result => {
            this.imageChangedEvent = { target: { files: [result] } };
            this.formatError = false;
            this.sizeError = false;
          });
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

I except the image to be resized before getting pushed in the cropper, but for now, even if it goes through all the resizing process, the image stays as it is when uploaded without the change in height and width.

Comment: Short question: Your math in your function `resizeImg` is working correctly and it is logging you different `height` and `width` values?

Comment: Not exactly, for example when I use a 640x960px image, after the image passes through the math, it's dimensions (image.width and image.height) are 186x280px, which is what I want.
But the problem is that image.src remains 640x960

Comment: Did you tried to draw the image on a canvas and then set the `img.src` again? Like `resized_img.src = canvas.toDataURL();` Here is what i used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33291682/5677688 or here https://www.liip.ch/en/blog/resizing-images-with-javascript

Comment: I've tried it before, but I did wrong. Now that I followed your 2nd link, it worked ! Thanks a lot !